# How to load and display the images in the folder with different name in the ImageView in android?

Tags: java, android

These is the code snippet of an Android program... Where I am trying to display images in an ImageView. But while making it dynamic by removing the constant values the program is giving me an error which I am not able to resolve...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        Class<drawable> resources = R.drawable.class;
        Field[] fields = resources.getFields();

        for (Field field : fields) 
        {
            imgName[n]=field.getName();
            n++;
        }
        while(cnt!=n)
        {
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName[cnt], "drawable","com.example.imageviewpckg");
            imgList[cnt]=resID;
            cnt++;
        }
}
```

Can we write the above code for initializing the `int` Array with ImageView `ids` instead of the fixed initialization as show below code of line...

This below line gives me the correct output:

```
int imgList[] ={
                  R.drawable.img1,
                  R.drawable.img2,
                  R.drawable.img3,
                  R.drawable.img4,
                  R.drawable.img5,
                  R.drawable.img7
                };
```

Comment: show us the error you're getting

Comment: **int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName[cnt], "drawable","com.example.imageviewpckg");**                                                                                                                         Error lies somewhere here..... Which i am not knowing?

Comment: 09-05 15:34:31.003: E/AndroidRuntime(284): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imageviewpckg/com.example.imageviewpckg.ImageViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-05 15:34:31.003: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-05 15:34:31.003: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-05 15:34:31.003: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at com.example.imageviewpckg.ImageViewActivity.onCreate(ImageViewActivity.java:46)-@Raghav